# Python Twitter streaming API - followed users only

Tags: python, twitter

I'm attempting to get the statuses of followed users only using the Python [Twitter](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) library. It works fine for the 'everyone' stream:

```
from twitter.stream import TwitterStream 
from twitter.oauth import OAuth 
from twitter.util import printNicely 

stream = TwitterStream(
    auth=OAuth(
                acc_key, acc_secret,
                con_key, con_secret),
                domain="userstream.twitter.com",
                api_version='1',
                secure=True)
print stream.statuses.sample()
tweet_iter = stream.statuses.sample() 
for tweet in tweet_iter: 
    if tweet.get('text'): 
        printNicely(tweet['text'])
```

But I want to restrict the output to users I follow only. As far as I can tell from the docs, `sample()` gives me everything, but I can't tell whether there's a `filter()` method. Should I be using a different library? I've been using Tweepy for non-streaming Twitter tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) for a Python Twitter library. It is regularly maintained, a useful property considering how often Twitter changes its API.

EDIT: See [tweetstream](https://bitbucket.org/runeh/tweetstream/src) for a simple streaming API implementation which as filtering capabilities.

Comment: @urschrei You are right. Neither library supports the `/filter` method natively.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, twython doesn't support support the userstream live stream. See [here](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/streaming.py). There doesn't seem to be much activity in its user group, either.

Comment: @sye this should have been a comment on your answer